# javascript calcultate function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am new for javascript, im trying to calculate function but not working

```
 <script>
     function calculator() {
         var first_name = document.getElementById('value1').value;
         //alert("first_name");
         var last_name = document.gerElementById('value2').value;
         var add = first_name + last_name;
         document.write("add");
     }
</script> 

<div id="cal">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"></td>
            <td><button onclick="calculator()" type="button">+</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please **explain** what *exactly* is not working. What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: are you trying to add two strings or numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested code working fine.**

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculator() {
            var first_name = document.getElementById('value1').value;
            //alert("first_name");
            alert(first_name);
            // var last_name = document.gerElementById('value2').value;
            var last_name = document.getElementById('value2').value;
            //var add = first_name+last_name;
            var add = parseInt(first_name) + parseInt(last_name);
            //document.write("add");
            document.write(add);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="value1" />
    <input id="value2" />
    <input type="button" onclick="calculator()" value="Add" />
</body>
</html>
```

Commented line show your code.

Comment: Please **explain** your answer, don't just post code. What did you change and why?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. All lines having problems are commented in answer and correct one is below the same line.

Comment: I understood that. But you haven't explained *why* the lines are incorrect. If I tell you that you should use `parseInt(first_name, 10)` instead of `parseInt(first_name)`, would you know why? Or would you also want an explanation from me?

Answer (score 1):

> function calculator()
>              {
>
> ```
>       var first_name = parseInt(document.getElementById('value1').value);
>         //alert("first_name");
>         var last_name = parseInt(document.getElementById('value2').value);
>         var add = first_name + last_name;
>         document.write(add);
>     }
> </script>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <table>
>         <tr>
>             <td><input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value=""></td>
>             <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"></td>
>             <td><button onclick="calculator()" type="button">+</button></td>
>         </tr>
>
>
>     </table>
>
>
>
> </div>
> ```

You need to parseInt to perform the addition 
else it will take the values as string and concatenate them

Answer (score 1):

You have typo here `gerElementById` it should be `getElementById`

```
var last_name = document.gerElementById('value2').value;
```

change it to

```
var last_name = document.getElementById('value2').value;
```

and of course you are writing a string not the variable `add` in the `document.write();`

change it with

```
document.write(add);
```

check this link as well http://jsfiddle.net/E9RVn/

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a string with the `"add"`

Remove the `"  "` quotations

```
document.write(add);
```

Answer (score 0):

They actually strings are not numbers. So, easiest way to produce a number from a string is to prepend it with `+`. Like :

```
var add = +first_name + +last_name;
```

Comment: @AlienArrays He is trying to calculate 2 numbers.. Please read the question.. And he is new to javascript. So that he is using some variables like `first_name` and `last_name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function calculator() {
     var first_name = document.getElementById('value1').value;
     //alert("first_name");
     var last_name = document.gerElementById('value2').value;
     var add = parseInt(first_name) + parseInt(last_name);
     document.write(add);
 }
</script> 

<div id="cal">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="value1" id="value1" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"></td>
        <td><button onclick="calculator()" type="button">+</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistakes in code.

- getElementById was incorrect
- Values were not parsed

Below is corrected:

```
<script>
     function calculator() {
         var first_name = parseInt(document.getElementById('value1').value, 10);
         //alert("first_name");
         var last_name = parseInt(document.getElementById('value2').value, 10);
         var add = first_name + last_name;
         document.write(add);
     }
</script> 

<div id="cal">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"></td>
            <td><button onclick="calculator()" type="button">+</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do calculation without parsing:

```
<script>
  function calculator() {
  var first_name = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var last_name = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var cal = first_name+"+"+last_name;
  var add = eval(cal);
  document.write(add);
 }
</script>
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp